# Ler uma SMS recebida

Tags: android, sms

Um App recebe um SMS e a partir do texto executa uma função.
Para isso é necessário ler a SMS e efetuar a comparação no APP, mas para isso deve-se 
ler, palavra por palavra, linha por linha ou fazer uma comparação se contém tal palavra nessa SMS.

A SMS vai ter o seguinte conteúdo.

Caso ocorra uma mudança de estado:
MONIT-110
E05-ATI
E06-DES

E a de todas as saídas:
STATUS-110
E01-DES
E02-DES
E03-DES
E04-DES
E05-DES
E06-DES
E07-DES
E08-DES
E09-DES
E10-DES
E11-DES
S01-DES
S02-DES
S03-DES
S04-DES
S05-DES
S06-DES

Para cada uma dessas linhas tem um comando diferente a ser executado.

Código responsável pela MSG recebida:

```
public class ReceberSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String CATEGORIA = "acqua";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(CATEGORIA, ">" + intent.getAction());

        Sms sms = new Sms();
        //Lê a mensagem
        SmsMessage msg = sms.receberMensagem(intent);
        String celular = msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        String mensagem = msg.getDisplayMessageBody();
        //pegar essa msg e jogar nas configurações

        String texto = "ReceberSms: recebeu sms[" + celular + "] -> " + mensagem;
        Log.i(CATEGORIA, texto);
        Toast.makeText(context, texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}//fim
```

Comment: Não entendi bem qual é a dúvida... Mas acredito que seja como quebrar o texto em *tokens*?

Comment: A sms que recebo contem comandos a duvida é como posso ler o conteúdo da sms para identificar os comandos que estão nela. Acho que seria como quebrar o texto em tokens mas não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: Vendo que você já tem o texto completo, acho que basta chamar o método `split`, passando o separador dos comandos. Seria legal talvez incluir um exemplo pra ajudar a encontrar a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Talves seja necessário que seja construído através de um vetor de objeto. Observe este código:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReceiveSMSActivity extends Activity{

    static TextView messageBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        messageBox=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageBox);
    }

    public static void updateMessageBox(String msg)
    {
        messageBox.append(msg);
    }

}
```

Esta aqui detecta e processa a mensagem:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class TextMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

        Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

        for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
            sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }

        for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
            ReceiveSMSActivity.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: "+msg.getOriginatingAddress()+"\n"+
                    "Message: "+msg.getMessageBody()+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Acho que falta como outro usuário disse, um comando, veja se consegue com este modelo acima.

Answer (score 0):

Se a string la do final do seu codigo ja contem fim de linha, mensagem, que vc leu na linha abaixo:

```
String mensagem = msg.getDisplayMessageBody();
```

Você pode utilizar o Split, como já citado pelo @Wakim, pela quebra de linhas e dopois pelo '-', e por ultimo um Switch para executar os comandos, ficaria algo assim:

```
String[] linhas = mensagem.split("\n"); // Veja qual o seu caracter de fim de linha.

for (String l : linhas){
   switch (l) {
         case "E01-DES":
             ...
             break;
         case "E02-DES":
             ...
         case ...

             break;
         default:
             Log.i("ALERTA","Sinal recebido não suportado: " + l);
     }
}
```

***Observe que este código é apenas um exemplo, eu faria esta função com o Switch fora do FOR, ou ainda separaria cada linha em duas novas Strings, e faria talvez uma função genérica para executar cada uma das ações. Mas precisaria de mais informações do seu código para isso.***